# I cannot get this cylinder to shade properly

Tags: modeling, rendering

Im trying to render this lid but i cant seem to get the texture to shade smooth. The models has been imported from solidworks. ive tried everything from edgesplit and subdivsion to UV mapping reduce the 'lines' when i render but im still new to blender and dont know what else to do. How do i get the main face (the cylindrical face) of the lid to render properly? [image]

Comment: Hello, it would be faster to re-do it from scratch, just create a cylinder, scale in down on Z in Edit mode, and bevel the top face

Comment: @moonboots I don't know if this is sufficient, there seems to be a notch or something in the top face.

Comment: was considering doing it from scratch but was wondering if there was anything i could do to keep the part as part of the assembly it was imported with as opposed to adding a new model first. but ill have to try re-doing it from scratch

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann oh ok you must be right

Comment: @Raeshaan Goh maybe share your file to see if we can shade smooth

Comment: how do i share the file?

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest remodelling. Find the dimensions of the object in Item Tab on the right 3D Viewport Menu
[image]

and manually set the dimensions on the new cylinder. Then just select the outer edge rim and *Ctrl+B* create the Bevel, or add *Bevel modifier*.

This area is causing the problem, since it is not a completely flat surface.

[image]

Comment: ill give that try thanks

Comment: This solution is more or less what @moonboots wrote in his comment, but still one questions persists: this is an imported object which seems to be designed with a notch on top. Of course that's what's making problems, but if it is intentionally there, simply creating a cylinder with a bevel will not create the same object. But since the OP doesn't seem to mind, it may be some mistake in the model... so, nevermind.